# Add class to django form widget field

Tags: jquery, css, django, django-forms

I have two models:

```
class Studio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Studio", max_length=30, unique=True)

class Film(models.Model):
    studio = models.ForeignKey(Studio, verbose_name="Studio")
    name = models.CharField("Film Name", max_length=30, unique=True)
```

And I want to create a form for Film.  The form should have a drop down for Studio, but allow the user to enter a new Studio if the one they need isn't already in the database.  **First, if there's a simpler way to implement this, let me know.**

But what I'm trying to do is include a "+" icon next to the Studio dropdown.  If this is clicked, it unhides a new field that allows the user to enter text for a new Studio.  I want to include a "-" button next to the unhid field that rehides it if the user changes their mind.  That's where I'm getting stuck.

My form currently looks like this:

```
class SelectWithPlus(forms.Select):
    def render(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        html = super(SelectWithPlus, self).render(name, *args, **kwargs)
        plus = render_to_string("form/plus.html", {'field': name})
        return html+plus

class DeSelectWithX(forms.CharField):
    def render(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        html = super(DeSelectWithX, self).render(name, *args, **kwargs)
        ex = render_to_string("form/ex.html", {'field': name})
        return html+ex

class FilmForm(forms.Form):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    studio = forms.ModelChoiceField(Studio.objects, widget = SelectWithPlus)
    new_studio = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, label = "New Studio Name", widget = DeSelectWithX)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label = "Film Name")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MdlForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['new_studio'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'hidden_studio_field'
```

The idea is that the studio field has a widget that adds a bit of html for a "+" icon:

```
<a
    href="JavaScript:void()"
    class="add-another"
    id="add_id_{{ field }}">
    <img src="http://mydbupload.s3.amazonaws.com/icon_addlink.gif" width="10" height="10" Border ="0" alt="Add New {{ field }}"/>
</a>
```

When this is clicked, it triggers jquery to show the fields named appropriately:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hidden_studio_field").hide();
        $('label[for="id_new_studio"]').hide();
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#add_id_studio').click(function() {
            $(".hidden_studio_field").show();
            $('label[for="id_new_studio"]').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

So I want to add a similar "-" button to the new_studio field.  I tried to replicate the SelectWithPlus widget, but the one snag I'm hitting is that I can no longer use the bit of code that adds the class "hidden_studio_field" to that field.  I get an error: 'DeSelectWithX' object has no attribute 'attrs'

So short question: **How do I add a css-type class to a field that is defined by a widget?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeSelectWithX` should inherit from `forms.TextInput`, not `forms.CharField`.